# Table that is spanning multiple pages in PDF to always have the table header

Tags: html, css, html-table, header, tr

I have a page with an HTML table inside it which can also be downloaded as a PDF. Now, the content of this table may vary - it can have many items that spans multiple pages in the downloadable PDF. Let's say the table took up five pages. The thing is, the table header only shows up at the top of the table, which is in the first page. Ideally I want it to show up for every instance of the cut-off table so anyone viewing the PDF would not have to go back to the first page just to see the table header and they can see it for every page.

Is this possible using CSS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"possible using CSS?"* ? Do you want an html solution or to "fix" the PDF file?... OR are you using a tool that converts *your* html to PDF? (That is to say, are you fixing your own data, or someone elses?). Please edit your question to clarify these issues rather than reply in comments. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the table elements of HTML to structure your table, you can take a look at `thead`.

What it will do when generating a PDF (utilizing @media print styling, if you have any) is placing a header on every page where the table exists. Let me know if this is unclear.

In summary, use `thead` for the header row and `tbody` for the content rows. Let me know how it goes :)